# Why does the current in the spring cause it to contract?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

If I close the switch in the set-up below, the spring will contract.

The mark scheme asking gives these four reasons:

1. Magnetic field around each coil is circular
2. Current in the coil interacts with magnetic field to exert a force on the coil
3. Force is normal to the coil and the field
4. Force between coils is attractive, so the spring contracts

However, I am confused about point 2.

The current in the coil is the reason there is a magnetic field in the first place, so how can it be the case that the current that generates the magnetic field interacts with its 'own' magnetic field to exert a force on the coil?

Can someone share some insight?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose it means that every "ring" of which the spring consists feels the magnetic field produced by other (neighbouring) "rings". You can also think of it as a parallel pair of wires conducting current in the same direction, but at the same time being a part of a single larger circuit: these wires attract.

Comment: Adding to the above answer: in the parallel wires example, the field due to one wire at the place where the second wire is , is calculated and taken to be "the magnetic field". Then the problem now becomes one of solving for the force when a current carrying wire is placed in a magnetic field. By newton's third law, an equal and opposite force is exerted on the other wire.